# Magento 2 : Get Quote Item Selected Options

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-options, quoteitem

I want to programmatically fetch quote item options which are currently selected.

I've added product with options like following;

Color : Red 
Size  : 6

[image]

Now I want to fetch that selected options programmatically in another Controller.

How can I do that.

Comment: Check in `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` u will get it `magento\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\form.phtml`

Comment: @AnkitShah How can I fetch selected options in another controller programetically? I want that code.

Answer (score 12):

You can usually call `$item->getProductOptions()` to get all options and then sort through to get selected options as mentioned by @Rakesh Jesadiya.

But, Sometimes `$item->getProductOptions()` returns `NULL`, then you can call

```
$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
```

instead and it will return options in the same format.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know how to do something, it's always best to look at how Magento does it. So if you take a look at the cart templates, you'll notice that the template responsible for rendering a default product (`module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml`) uses a method `getOptionList()` to get the options:

```
<?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
    ... etc.
```

Now take a look at this method (`Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer::getOptionList()`):

```
public function getOptionList()
{
    return $this->getProductOptions();
}
```

And `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer::getProductOptions()` will do the following:

```
public function getProductOptions()
{
    /* @var $helper \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration */
    $helper = $this->_productConfig;
    return $helper->getCustomOptions($this->getItem());
}
```

Now this is interesting, because here we see the use of a helper that does exactly what your question is: get the custom options of a quote item. And it's a helper, so you can use dependency injection to use it in your own code.

A simple example:

```
class Example
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration
     */
    protected $configurationHelper;

    /**
     * Example constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $configurationHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $configurationHelper
    )
    {
        $this->configurationHelper = $configurationHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface $item
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSelectedOptionsOfQuoteItem(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemInterface $item)
    {
        return $this->configurationHelper->getCustomOptions($item);
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

Using Magento 2.1.6

Answer (score 2):

You need to load quote item and call below functions,

```
public function getSelectedOptions($item){
     $result = [];
        $options = $item->getProductOptions();
        if ($options) {
            if (isset($options['options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['options']);
            }
            if (isset($options['additional_options'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['additional_options']);
            }
            if (isset($options['attributes_info'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $options['attributes_info']);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

You can get selected option by below blog in magento 2, [Get Selected options Using Magento 2](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-order-item-selected-options-in-magento-2/)

Using above Blog you can get Selected options value either by Quote or Order Object.
Above link is used for Configurable and Bundle product selected options.

Comment: Thnanks for the answer. I already find this solutions.

Comment: $options = $item->getProductOptions(); In my case $options is blank. Can you please guide? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find that doing an optimised query using the `Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface` on information readily accessible `getOptions` method on an `$item` was the best performer for me:

```php
    /**
     * @param Item $item
     * @return string
     */
    public function newActionVarientFromCartItem(CartItemInterface $item): string
    {
        $variants = [];
        $delimiter = $this->configValue(static::CONFIG_PATH_GAEE_CATEGORY_SEPARATOR_DELIMITER);
        $options = $item->getOptions();
        if (count($options)) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                if ($option->getCode() === 'attributes') {
                    $values = $this->serialiser->unserialize($option->getValue());
                    foreach ($values as $attrId => $attrOptId) {
                        $connection = $this->newResourceConnection();
                        $t1 = $connection->getTableName('eav_attribute_option');
                        $t2 = $connection->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');
                        $w1 = $connection->prepareSqlCondition('eao.attribute_id', ['eq' => $attrId]);
                        $w2 = $connection->prepareSqlCondition('eaov.option_id', ['eq' => $attrOptId]);
                        $w3 = $connection->prepareSqlCondition('eaov.store_id', ['in' => [0, $item->getStoreId()]]);
                        $select = $connection
                            ->select()
                            ->from(['eao' => $t1], 'eaov.value')
                            ->joinInner(['eaov' => $t2], "eao.option_id=eaov.option_id")
                            ->where(implode(' AND ', [$w1, $w2, $w3]))
                            ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('eaov.store_id' . ' ' . SortOrder::SORT_DESC));

                        // var_dump($select->__toString());
                        $variants[] = (string) $connection->fetchOne($select);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return implode($delimiter, $variants);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new connection to the database
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnectionFactory $this->_resourceConnectionFactory
     * @return AdapterInterface
     */
    public function newResourceConnection(): AdapterInterface
    {
        return $this->_resourceConnectionFactory
            ->create()
            ->getConnection();
    }
```

Personally this command:

```php
$item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
```

Was not very performant for me.